# How to install CakePHP plugins from Composer into app/Plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.0, composer-php

I'm trying to install this plugin: https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/
into my CakePHP project using Composer. And everything was smooth, but it installed into *[project root]/Plugin* (directory created by Composer I guess) instead of *[project root]/app/Plugin*.

Obviously, in that case, it's impossible to load it by using:

```
<?php
//app/Config/bootstrap.php
CakePlugin::load('Mongodb');
```

If I manually move it to the second dir, it works just fine. But then I have two directories, which is terribly misleading.
I know from my experience that one will eventually assume the plugin gets updated while in fact, in app/Plugin there's an older version of it, the one i had to manually copy there.

So my question is:
How do I do install CakePHP plugins from Composer properly, so they go into app/Plugin?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the required plugin line to `/app/composer.json` instead of adding it to `/composer.json`.

Minimum contents of `app/composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb": "2.2.*@dev"
    }
}
```

Then just run **composer update** from your console while in the app folder instead of from your project's root folder. This will install it to the Plugin directory relative to your current position on the server.

Comment: Wow, that's neat solution. Thanks, I wouldn't have thought of that, haha!

Comment: Glad to be able to help!